# pasar datos a un archivo txt

Tags: c#, .net, lista

Hola Comunidad espero que se encuentren muy bien 
estoy intentando pasar una lista  a un txt de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

generar un TXT con esos datos al seleccionar Guardar. 
Mi código es el siguiente el cual ya genera un txt 
pero como pasar esos datos ??

```
   string[]  lines = { "Primera Línea", "Segunda Línea", "Tercera Línea" };


        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Gustabo\Pictures\a\EscribeLineas.txt", lines);
```

Esa es la linea que me genera y guarda el txt

```
  List<object> lista = new List<object>();
        object respuesta = null;
        int total = 0;
        try
        {

            var cuenta = from elemento in db.CaracteristicasPA
                         join trafico in db.Trafico

                              on elemento.Trafico_Id equals trafico.Id
                         where
                         elemento.Activo == 1 && elemento.Id_LineaNegocio == lineaNegocio

                         select new
                         {
                             elemento.Id,
                             elemento.Sentido,
                             elemento.Trafico_Id,
                             trafico.Descripcion,
                             elemento.Cuenta,
                             elemento.Nlicencia,
                             elemento.Region,
                             elemento.Ambito,
                             elemento.Canal,
                             elemento.Bundle,
                             elemento.Subtipolinea,
                             elemento.Producto,
                             elemento.Segmentopa,
                             elemento.SubsegmentoPA,
                             elemento.Material,
                             elemento.IdCodigoCuenta,
                         };

            foreach (var elemento in cuenta)
            {
                lista.Add(new
                {
                    Id = elemento.Id,
                    Sentido = elemento.Sentido,
                    Trafico_Id = elemento.Trafico_Id,
                    TraficoDescripcion = elemento.Descripcion,
                    Cuenta = elemento.Cuenta,
                    Nlicencia = elemento.Nlicencia,
                    Region = elemento.Region,
                    Ambito = elemento.Ambito,
                    Canal = elemento.Canal,
                    Bundle = elemento.Bundle,
                    Subtipolinea = elemento.Subtipolinea,
                    Producto = elemento.Producto,
                    Segmentopa = elemento.Segmentopa,
                    SubsegmentoPA = elemento.SubsegmentoPA,
                    Material = elemento.Material,
                    IdCodigoCuenta = elemento.IdCodigoCuenta
                });
            }
            total = lista.Count();
            lista = lista.Skip(start).Take(limit).ToList();
            respuesta = new { success = true, results = lista, total = total };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            respuesta = new { success = true, results = "no" };
        }
        return Json(respuesta, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

y esa es la lista la cual obtengo de una tabla llamada CaracteristicasPA que contiene los siguientes campos para agregar. Trato de guardar en el txt. con esos campos de la tabla. Por favor podrian ayudarme a resolver este problema

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes una entidad seria recomendable generes la clase equivalente y no usar una anonima, entonces deberias definir

```
public class CaracteristicasTrafico
{
    public int Id  {get;set;}
    public string Sentido {get;set;}
    public int Trafico_Id {get;set;}
    //otras propiedades
}
```

Entonces cuando defines el `select` del linq usas esa clase

```
var cuenta = ....
             select new CaracteristicasTrafico()
                     {
                         Id = elemento.Id,
                         Sentido = elemento.Sentido,
                         Trafico_Id = elemento.Trafico_Id,
                      //resto propiedades
```

El `foreach (var elemento in cuenta){...` esta de mas mas, no necesitas convertir a una lista de objeto porque es lo mismo que tener la anonima.

Al tener una clase puede redefinir el `ToString()`

```
public class CaracteristicasTrafico
{
    public int Id  {get;set;}
    public string Sentido {get;set;}
    public int Trafico_Id {get;set;}
    //otras propiedades

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, ...", this.Id, this.Sentido, this.Trafico_Id, ...);
    }
}
```

Entonces si podras generar el archivo usando

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\..\EscribeLineas.txt", cuenta.Select(x=>x.ToString()));
```

Asi tendras cada linea con sus datos separados por comas

---

Otra alternativa mas simples es usar una libreria, como ser:

[filehelpers](https://www.filehelpers.net/)

con este puede mapear la clase a un archivo de forma directa

[Write Delimited File](https://www.filehelpers.net/example/QuickStart/WriteFileDelimited/)

Comment: Muchísimas Gracias!!!! :D